# Java rest elastic search json documents

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I am trying to sends json documents to elasticsearch by using java rest .

I just need to know how to initialize the variable "entities[i]" and put json documents in its.I have try many ways but still do not get something which work.

here is the code from elastticsearch website: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_example_requests.html

```
int numRequests = 10;
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numRequests);

for (int i = 0; i < numRequests; i++) {
    restClient.performRequestAsync(
        "PUT",
        "/twitter/tweet/" + i,
        Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(),
        //assume that the documents are stored in an entities array
        entities[i],
        new ResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Response response) {
                System.out.println(response);
                latch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                latch.countDown();
            }
        }
    );
}

//wait for all requests to be completed
latch.await();
```

Thanks you

Comment: Post some of the ways you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int numRequests = 1;
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numRequests);

    HttpEntity entity = new NStringEntity(
            "{\n" +
                    "    \"user\" : \"kimchy\",\n" +
                    "    \"post_date\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" +
                    "    \"message\" : \"trying out Elasticsearch\"\n" +
                    "}", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    List<HttpEntity> entities = asList(entity);

    for (int i = 0; i < numRequests; i++) {
        restClient.performRequestAsync(
                "PUT",
                "/twitter/tweet/" + i,
                Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(),
                entities.get(i),
                new ResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Response response) {
                        System.out.println(response);
                        latch.countDown();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    latch.await();
```

The entity is a type HttpEntity.You need to create list of HttpEntity objects in the list and use them.

Comment: I think that the snippet you posted will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: Just try now changed it now try. So example was to explain the entity object .

Comment: by the way, you're going to want to start accepting answers to your questions: read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers